# Update multiple rows with unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update multiple rows so all rows will have unique id? For example:

MyTable:

```
id/product_id/price/sell_price/amount  
231/122/10/5/6  
276/122/5/3/16  
298/122/20/12/60  
210/122/100/55/1
```

Now if I insert these values into temporary table

```
(select * into #tmp_table from MyTable where product_id=122)
```

Now I would like to make some changes and insert these values back into the original table "MyTable", but I am struggling here, how to get unique id values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the table, use `update` with `join`:

```
update t
    set ? = tt.?
    from MyTable t join
         #tmp_table tt
         on t.id = tt.id;
```

It is unclear what values you want to set, but just put the appropriate logic in the `set` clause.

EDIT:

Based on your comment.  You should simply define the `id` column to be an `identity` column.  Then:

```
insert into MyTable (product_id, price, sell_price, amount)
    select product_id, price, sell_price, amount
    from #tmp_table;
```

You can also generate new ids, if you like:

```
insert into MyTable (id, product_id, price, sell_price, amount)
    select x.maxid + row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,
           tt.product_id, tt.price, tt.sell_price, tt.amount
    from #tmp_table tt cross join
         (select max(id) as maxid from MyTable) x;
```

But an identity id seems more in the spirit of the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I expressed myself a bit unclearly. Actually I dont want to update existing records, I would like to have these in place, but want to insert new values based on existing values. In the final results I would like to see 8 rows with unique id values, based on this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple update with join on temp table or merge

```
UPDATE y 
    set y.amount = t.amount+100  --your update columns
    from yourProduct y
    inner join #tmp t
    on y.id = t.id and y.product_id = t.product_id
```

your table

```
create table yourProduct (id int, product_id int, price int, sell_price int, amount int)

insert into yourProduct (id, product_id, price, sell_price, amount) values
 (231,122,10 ,5 ,6  )
,(276,122,5  ,3 ,16 ) 
,(298,122,20 ,12,60 ) 
,(210,122,100,55,1  )


select * into #tmp from yourProduct where product_id = 122
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I expressed myself a bit unclearly. Actually I dont want to update existing records, I would like to have these in place, but want to insert new values based on existing values.
In the final results I would like to see 8 rows with unique id values, based on this example.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to add a new column with incremented product id:s.

```
alter table MyTable add productid Int Identity(1,1)
```

You can then drop the old column if the old product id:s will be used.

```
alter table MyTable drop column product_id
```

If you wish to use the old name of the column use:

```
exec sp_rename 'productid', 'MyTable.product_id', 'column';
```

I would highly suggest to, when you done this, add the UNIQUE-constraint to this column in order to protect yourself from duplicate product-id:s in the future.

```
alter table MyTable
add unique (product_id);
```